# SQL DATEDIFF add plus sign if number is positive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I am using `DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2)` and it works great.

Is it possible to have the plus sign if a number is positive and if it is negative, it has a minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can CAST or CONVERT the output to a string, and then add the '+' sign if required (the minus will already be there if it is negative.

```
Case When DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2) > 0 Then '+' Else '' End + Cast (DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2) as VarChar(10))
```

Here is an example

```
;With MyTable as
(
    Select GETDATE() as Date1, GetDate()+10 as Date2
)
Select 
    Case When DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2) > 0 Then '+' Else '' End + Cast (DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2) as VarChar(10))
    From MyTable


;With MyTable as
(
    Select GETDATE() as Date1, GetDate()-10 as Date2
)
Select 
    Case When DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2) > 0 Then '+' Else '' End + Cast (DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2) as VarChar(10))
    From MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEDIFF( day, date1, date2),'+#;-#;0')
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DECLARE @date1 as datetime 
DECLARE @date2 as datetime 
DECLARE @datediff as varchar(10) 
SET @date1 = GETDATE() - 10
SET @date2 = GETDATE() - 1
SET @datediff = DATEDIFF( day, @date1, @date2)

 SELECT Case 
    When @datediff > 0 Then '+'
      Else '-' 
 End + @datediff
```